# Center a UIImageView and a UILabel together in a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton, uilabel

If I declare a UILabel and a UIImageView of different sizes can I then center them in a UIView with 10.0points between the two horizontally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Basically what you need is appropiate constraints. You can add constraints from code or in stoaryboard

**Code example:**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:5];
[view addConstraint:constraint];
```

[NSLayoutConstraint Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/)

[Auto Layout Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[Adaptive Layout Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using AutoLayout.
You cans set the right margin of the label to be 5 points to the left of the superview CenterX and the imageview left margin to be 5 points to the right of the superview CenterX.